# Compare exec stdout with some text using shelljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, shelljs

When running `sh.exec('whoami')` I am trying to compare the stdout but it doesn't work.

What I want to do is that after running the `whoami` command if the results turns to be an specific user then I would like to trigger an action.

When running,

```
sh.exec('whoami', (code, output) => {
  sh.echo(output == 'myusername'); // False
  console.log(output == 'myusername'); // False
});
```

The condition `output == 'myusername'` evaluates to false even though I am completely sure it is true since I've copied the username and place it as the compared string.

The expected result would be that the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: try to log `output`. Then it might have some spaces. Also try to compare them `char` by `char` to see if they are using same unicode

Comment: `whoami` outputs a trailing linefeed. Maybe getting `'myusername\n'` as output?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @AntihypeBird! I did as you said and noticed stdout puts an extra \n at the end.

Comment: @gmotzespina no problem. Glad you solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Doing,

```
 console.log(sh.exec('whoami'));
```

You get the following output,

```
{ [String: 'username\n']
  stdout: 'username\n',
  stderr: '',
  code: 0,
  cat: [Function: bound ],
  exec: [Function: bound ],
  grep: [Function: bound ],
  head: [Function: bound ],
  sed: [Function: bound ],
  sort: [Function: bound ],
  tail: [Function: bound ],
  to: [Function: bound ],
  toEnd: [Function: bound ],
  uniq: [Function: bound ] 
}
```

The problem was just a new line. `stdout` comes with a `\n` at the end.

Comment: In the body of your callback function passed to `exec` consider utilizing the [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method to remove the `\n` before checking for equality. For Instance: `sh.exec('whoami', (code, output) => { sh.echo(output.trim() === 'myusername'); });`